# Can you put iOS icon & launch images in a different directory to the project root?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4.5

I have a cross-platform codebase, structured a bit like this:

```
/Projects
 /App1
  /src
  /iOS
 /App2
  /src
  /iOS
 /App3
  /src
  /iOS
 Win32.sln
 iOS.xcodeproj
```

XCode wants to put icons and launch images under /Projects, as siblings of the .xcodeproj file, but that's messy - these are project/target-specific files. I would rather have each app keep app-specific iOS files under e.g. App2/iOS.

I've seen some topics on this kind of issue, talking about how xcode wants to copy images to the root, but no definitive answer if you can or can't do it.

edit: the same goes for my app .plist file, can I relocate this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found these are all possible

The plist file is easiest, there is a build setting `info.plist` which must be updated accordingly.

For the icon and launch images, remove references from your project and then move the files on disc to some folder that makes sense for your codebase. Then add these items to the project (right-click, "add files to "). Finally, use a copy files build phase to copy them to the *Resource* folder, or possibly add them to a Copy Resource Bundle build phase.

When I did this, the files were copied into the App-Bundle itself, the iPad displayed them as expected, and XCode displayed the images in the Project Summary screen.

Answer (score 1):

Currently the project I'm working on has the load screen icon in root folder and the appIcons under Resources/Icons so there's definitely a way of copying them there.

Try copying the icons to the desired folder manually, then add them to your project and uncheck "Copy items into destination group folder".

Also, I would advise you to create folders using finder, then adding them into Xcode to use them as Groups instead of creating them in Xcode.